# Golang program requiring uint64 compiling for 32 bit architecture

Tags: go, arm, 32bit-64bit

I am currently working on a program where I need to store big integer values, big enough that they don't fit into `uint32`. Only `int64` or `uint64`.

I just realized the `Raspberry Pi Zero v1.3`, that I will be using for this project, has `Broadcom BCM2835 processor`, which I believe is a `32 bit` architecture processor.

`It contains an ARM1176JZFS (ARM11 using an ARMv6-architecture core) with floating point, running at 1GHz`

How do I ensure my program functions correctly on this 32 bit architecture? Do I have to do anything differently? Or does the compiler is able to handle this without a problem when I cross compile it: `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=6 go build`?

Comment: On 32-bit architecture, `int` will be `int32`, so you might want to check all `int`s. If you explicitly declared variables as `int32` or int64`, they will work just fine.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Gotcha! But is it really just that? I don't even need to test separately for 32-bit architecture in any way? If you can add any additional info as to how does the compiler handles this in an answer, that would be great.

Comment: The only architecture dependent types are int, uint, and uintptr. You should explicitly check those. Any untyped numeric literal passed as interface{} will also be int, so you should check those as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @BurakSerdar Do you wanna post that as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Also thanks random guy who downvoted the question without a comment, you managed to give away a bit of your time without contributing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the disclaimer: I don't write 32-bit code, so what I say may be incomplete.

According to the language spec, the only architecture dependent types are int, uint, and uintptr. That means, you have to go back and check every piece of data and function argument declared as one of these types. You also have to check any untyped numeric literal (declared constants and literal values) passes as interface{}, because those will be passed as int as well.